# Magento 2: Post Code isn't being validated as 'required' on Checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, validation, form-validation

On my theme, the customer is allowed to proceed to the payment page of the checkout without having to add a Postcode, despite it being set as required. The other fields (Street, City) are required and validate correctly when they're left empty (the user is prevented from proceeding to the next step).

Any ideas why this is the case?

Comment: The Js form doesn't validate?

Comment: Correct. The 'This is a required field.' doesn't appear and just allows the user to proceed

Comment: How about your issue?

Comment: No, neither option worked :-(

Answer (score 1):

On the checkout page, by default, the Postal Code are required field.

*vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml*

```
<item name="postcode" xsi:type="array">
    <!-- post-code field has custom UI component -->
    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/post-code</item>
    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="string">true</item>
    </item>
</item>
```

[image]

So, you should **check this field in your custom layout**. Make sure the Required validation is enabled.

Additionally, if you want to make this attribute to be required on the server side also, you can use a simple query to :

```
UPDATE eav_attribute a SET a.`is_required` = 1 WHERE a.`attribute_code` = 'postcode';
```

Comment: I'm aware. But mine isn't.

Comment: Your custom theme has this field?

Comment: We have Luma theme in use and it is not validating ZIP and let's all ZIP's through. Just a warning. That checkout_index_index.xml is not present in Luma.

Answer (score 0):

- In Magento 2 we can specify the Zip/Postal Code is Optional for countries.
- In Magento admin Go to Stores > Configuration >General > General
- for "Zip/Postal Code is Optional for" = Select countries for which you want to zip code option
- Save
- Flush cache